# Twitter Bootstrap nav nav-tabs don't change on click

Tags: css, grails, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I like how the nav-tabs looks so I want to use it. This is how the web application looks right now:

[image: nav nav-tabs screenshot]

Unfortunately, if I click on other tab (for example "Buscar alojamiento"), the active tab doesn't change. This is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li>        
        <g:link controller="usuario" action="show">         
            <g:message code="nav.usuario.show" default="Datos del usuario" />           
        </g:link>       
    </li>   

    <li class="active">
        <a href="${createLink(uri: '/')}">
            <g:message code="nav.home" default="Página de inicio" />
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>        
        <g:link controller="alojamiento" action="show">         
            <g:message code="nav.alojamiento.show" default="Buscar alojamiento" />          
        </g:link>       
    </li>   

</ul>
```

I also try removing class="active". No tab is active ever doing that.

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Grails.

Comment: `<g:link...` is Grails @JamesKleeh`

Comment: There is not Javascript here @AntarrByrd

Comment: Is any of the answer helpful and appropriate for acceptance?

Comment: well, I guess the answer is the comment of @SérgioMichels of the answer he also wrote (this is the comment: Handle class="active" according to the current page). I think checking that answer as correct is the most appropiate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the "Tabbable Nav" example in the Twitter Bootstrap Components. You must have the correct html to this work. Example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#other" data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
     <p>Home</p>
   </div>
   <div id="other" class="tab-pane">
     <p>Other</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the `class` applied and the `href` of the links.

**UPDATE**

As we have discussed in the comments, we also can change it with Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    document.getElementById("home").setAttribute("class","active")
```

Or JQuery:

```
$('#home').attr('class','active')
```

Comment: Told you. We are pulpiteers of same gospel. This time you have a detailed answer. ;)

Comment: I'm trying to use `nav nav-tabs` to act like `navbar-inner`. I mean, if we click on a normal link it won't show a `tab-pane`. It will jump to the clicked link. How could I change the look of the `navbar-inner` to look as the `nav nav-tabs`?

Comment: @chelder you want to go to that link, or just show the content of that link in the tab?

Comment: I want to go to that link. It goes to that link right now, but the active tab doesn't change after clicking on it.

Comment: OMG. Yes! I didn't realize. Something like `<script type="text/javascript">` ...
`document.getElementById("tab1Id").setAttribute("class","active")` should work :)

Comment: You can also use JQuery -> `$('#tab1Id').attr('class','active')`

Answer (score 3):

You would need [Tabbable Nav](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs) to toggle between the contents of each tab.

Comment: I put my code between `<div class="tabbable">`. Nothing changed.

Comment: Follow the example shown in bootstrap page or follow what Sergio has stated, both mean the same thing. @chelder